# Unable to invoke async test job: Subscriber handshake failed due to a socket timeout

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins, ci, test-automation

there is a known issue [SFDX- when using in JENKINS :sfdx force:apex:test:run: An ERROR: Unable to invoke async test job: Subscriber handshake failed due to a socket timeout](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Hl9rQAC) on trailblazer site with no workaround specified.

i wanted to share my one, hopefully it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the core reason for that error is SFDC "forgets" to which instances it's connected. at least my setup started to show me the error in 2-3 weeks of night builds.

i do not use pipeline, but a freestyle project in Jenlinks. so my workaround is to run

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

before any

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run
```

it seems, in case of Pipeline the code should be the following:

```
command "${toolbelt}/sfdx force:org:list"
```

i'd add that command as the first line to "Authorize DevHub" stage of that [Jenkinsfile Walkthrough](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_jenkins_sample_walkthrough.htm). in my case, that issue does not return for 3-4 months already.